# Page not found instead of opening app screen go_router with deep link

Tags: flutter, deep-linking, flutter-go-router

I am following this [docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/set-up-app-links)
and when using the command

```
adb shell 'am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW \
    -c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE \
    -d "https://yassinebenkhay.com/details"' \
    com.example.deeplink_cookbook
```

it works as expected, it opens the details screen, but when I try to open the deep link

https://yassinebenkhay.com/details

in the browser of the same device where the app is installed, it takes me to my website with a page not found instead of opening the app details screen.

My androidManifest:

```
  <meta-data android:name="flutter_deeplinking_enabled" android:value="true" />
 <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="https" android:host="yassinebenkhay.com" />
</intent-filter>
```

`assetlinks.json` is properly set up and can be accessed from:
https://yassinebenkhay.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json

Am I doing something wrong?